Latch LS374 works for sometimes and doesn't work at all next clocks
I'm trying to interface with an 8080bus, that's the schematic of the socket of it:

Image: Partial schematic by Akai of their MPC2000XL showing the LCD interface, hosted on Mediafire
I'm latching all of the signals, A1,CS1,CS2, IOWR as clock to LS374, and the databus.
Here is the schematic of the board that has the two latches connected

I'm powering the latches from STM32F429I Discovery board, 5V, GND.
The ground of the Device 8080 is connected to STM32Board and to the PCB of the two latches.
I captured the data using logic analyzer, here is the data:
MPC LATCH IOWR
6E 30 1
7E 30 1
7A 30 1
21 30 0
21 30 1 
21 21 1 <--- latch is valid here
7F 21 1
7E 21 1
7F 21 1
7A 21 1
6A 21 1
7A 21 1
71 21 1
61 21 1
66 21 1
76 21 1
7A 21 1
6A 21 1
7A 21 1
78 21 1
68 21 1
60 21 1
70 21 1
76 21 1
7F 21 1
6F 21 1
60 21 1
7F 21 1
6F 21 1
61 21 1
7D 21 1
6E 21 1
78 21 1
7F 21 1
6F 21 1
6A 21 1
7A 21 1
71 21 1
61 21 1
68 21 1
78 21 1
74 21 1
24 21 1
21 21 1
6F 21 1
62 21 1
72 21 1
7A 21 1
79 21 1
69 21 1
63 21 1
7F 21 1
78 21 1
79 21 1
69 21 1
6E 21 1
67 21 1
77 21 1
7D 21 1
6D 21 1
6F 21 1
7F 21 1
76 21 1
66 21 1
60 21 1
70 21 1
78 21 1
7A 21 1
6A 21 1
61 21 1
70 21 1
73 21 1
3E 21 0
3E 3E 1 <--- latch is valid here
7F 3E 1
70 3E 1
7E 3E 1
6F 3E 1
60 3E 1
70 3E 1
78 3E 1
68 3E 1
60 3E 1
70 3E 1
77 3E 1
67 3E 1
6F 3E 1
7F 3E 1
70 3E 1
75 3E 1
65 3E 1
6E 3E 1
7E 3E 1
7A 3A 1 <--- latch is corrupted here
20 12 1 <--- latch is corrupted here
20 3A 0 <--- latch is corrupted here
20 20 1
7F 20 1
75 20 1
65 20 1
6F 20 1
7F 20 1
77 20 1
67 20 1
69 20 1
79 20 1
7F 20 1
6F 20 1
7F 20 1
70 20 1
68 20 1
78 20 1

I have no idea what's going wrong, and why the latch works for few moments and then is corrupted.


You might have said this in a previous question that you would like to emulate or capture LCD bus data, but please can you give the details of the LCD bus here too. Is it even an LS TTL compatible bus if you are using LS TTL chips? What pulse length the Write has? Why does your schematic have no bypass caps? Why are you feeding the STM32 with 5V signals from LS TTL chip; have you verified that the pins you use are 5V tolerant instead of 3V3 only?

@Justme here is the details of LCD bus data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168288/reverse-engineer-lcd-protocol-used-in-mpc2000xl/78377225#78377225

I don't know if its LS TTL compatible bus or no, how do I verify that please?
I will add bypass caps
I'm not feeding STM32 with 5V, instead I feed LS TTL chip from STM32 5V


The behaviour of the '374 is specified in the function table on p. 3 of the datasheet. Assuming that the chip is not broken, the most likely problem is that the input signals are not correct. You have to capture the relevant signals (C, D, Q) with an oscilloscope at the time the latch becomes corrupted.

@CL. How are the input signals are not correct ? I just have logic analyzer, not oscilloscope :(.

I am not worried about the data at an abstract level but on an electrical level. If you don't know the bus specs then measure it - at least the CS signals come from a HC type CMOS chip, it may be a CMOS bus but LS TTl chips may work on it. How is your wiring; you can't have long cables on this kind of bus. And 3) yes you are. Your 5V chips output 5V to a 3.3V STM. It may have damaged if you fed 5V into a 3.3V tolerant pin. LS chips don't output exactly 5V but typically more than 3.3V and the high output is rather weak. It's still wrong and not recommended.

@Justme so your suggestion is to replace the LS with HCT for example to solve this instability ? or there is something that you think is mysterious around ?

@andre no, I am definitely not suggesting to replace LS with HCT. HCT has 5V outputs and your MCU gets fried if you give 5V into 3.3V pins. And the problem might not be mysterious. You have not shown how do you wire all those boards together.

@Justme so what is still wrong and not recommended? Can you suggest a solution please ?

@andre there's not enough info to know why it does not work and therefore there is no solution yet. But at least you cannot connect 5V chip outputs to a 3.3V MCU for sure.

@Justme Input voltage on any other pin VSS − 0.3V 4.0V MAX
this from STM32 Electrical manual

@Justme The STM has 5V tolerant, so its not a problem to feed it from 5V Chip, I confirmed that from datasheet

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@andre It does say that, but please understand that it is an absolute maximum level before permanent damage happens. For non-5V tolerant pins, the normal operating conditions are up to VDD+0.3V or 3.6V in your case. Not all pins are 5V tolerant so you need to check all pins individually. Do not expect all pins to be 5V tolerant.

@Justme so it will damage the latch, or ST ?

@Justme I'm using PC6, PD0 to PD10, which inside the datasheet they are FT,
reference https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f427vg.pdf
Page 63

@andre That is not the problem then; all are FT pins. Please take a photo how you wired these together. It's possible the wiring couples a nearby signal such as A1 toggling to the IOWR signal.

@Justme Can you suggest me some checks to do ? tasks to check where is the problem please ?

Latches are level sensitive, registers are edge sensitive. If you want latches, then use 74ls373/573. We have no idea of how fast your logic analyser samples. It could be missing glitches or even valid transitions.  If you can measure the timings of the signals, you may not even need the latches as the microcontrollermay be fast enough to capture the data.

@Kartman I have used STM32F429I for that purpose alone without any Latches/inverter. and It didn't work. I have used several methods, Timer trigger DMA based on IOWR rising edge, still didn't work. Interrupt on IOWR, then write the LCD commands that I capture on portD, still didn't work.

@andre It is possible that these did not work for the same reason. But with the info you give is not enough to figure out the reason. Like, you never described or posted a photo of the wiring. It won't work if wiring is too long or otherwise not able to pass high frequency signals.

@Justme The wiring from MPC to PCB of latches is 40CM, and from Latches PCB to STM is 20CM, I will post a picture

40cm! You’ll need a gnd between each signal otherwise you’ll get crosstalk which would explain your symptoms. Get your wiring distance as short as possible. If it didn’t work with the micro direct, why do you think latching or registering the data is going to work any better? You need to generate some timing diagrams otherwise you’ll be guessing and go around in circles.

@Kartman Can you tell me an approach without latches,..etc ? Just with STM32?

Use an external interrupt and in the isr, read the data and address. I used a teensy4.1 to emulate the bus on a HP85 computer. Google HP EBTKS. And you’ll find the board I designed. The teensy4.1 is stupid fast. Probably overkill for your task but you need to be aware of timing.

You expect a high speed computer bus to work over a 40cm cabling.
Even if assumed that everything was done by the book, it would be a stretch.
I am just surprised the original system did not stop working as the bus is completely unbuffered and you extended it by 40cm out of the original system.
All the chips onboard the PCB share the same data wires.
For the latches and the original system to work, you need to put the latches right where the original LCD is, so that you don't degrade the bus signals any more that necessary.
It would be better to put buffers to isolate the original system from your extensions right at the display and then put a 40cm cable if needed, and design it in a way that the signals survive the 40cm cable.
The original STM32 may have worked too if put right at the display connector.

I have posted the pictures. What do you mean Original STM32 ? So normal way of Interrupting on IOWR, then read the databus ?

@andre Yeah if you can just piggyback very short connections between original LCD and original synth module it may work. The STM32 could use DMA for capturing the signals on clock edge.

Thanks so much!. Could you tell an approach please for DMA ? detailed one, might be in the answer as well ? Many thanks again

Please I need a definited answer, I'm making a PCB for the project.
But I need to test now, connectivity between MPC and STM, without latches without any in the middle.
The wires before was like >60CM
MPC bus signals are like > 16MHz
Can 4CM wires between MPC and STM would work
but there are 11 PINs
they will be in paralle

Unless you have all the specs, then you can’t expect a definitive answer. Because you are reverse engineering this, expect problems. PCBs are so cheap these days it is economical to prototype with them. If the first one didn’t work, try again. Design it such that you can have latches or registers or straight through by using 0 ohm resistors.  I don’t think DMA is needed here or whether it would work too well. I would add some logic to gate the Iowr with the selects in order to generate an interrupt. As mentioned before, you really need to have a timing diagram derived from logic analysis.
